# How do use HttpWebRequest to login into a website

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

Can some one help me figure out how to login into a page using HttpWebRequest and subsequently scrape a page. The code am using doesnt just writes out the markup on the login page but cannot login...the website am trying to login into is a php based site.

```
        // first, request the login form to get the viewstate value
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("loginPageUrl") as HttpWebRequest;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(
              webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
           );
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();


        string postData = String.Format("Username={0}&Password={1}", "user", "pwd");

        // have a cookie container ready to receive the forms auth cookie
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        // now post to the login form
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("loginPostUrl") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postData);
        requestWriter.Close();

        // we don't need the contents of the response, just the cookie it issues
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

        // now we can send out cookie along with a request for the protected page
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create("PageToScrapeUrl") as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
        responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        // and read the response
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();

        Console.WriteLine(responseData);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: very few pages with auth are **intended** to be scraped, and is frequently against the ToS. More commonly, if that data is *intended* to be used like this, there will be a programmatic API. Use the API.

Comment: For the case you are allowed to scrape: Have you checked the traffic with fiddler? You will have to analyze the successfull login with a browser using the original page and simulate the webrequest. Maybe there are some other fields getting posted to the server?

Comment: Can you give us the url of the site? It will be a lot easier to see where are you wrong as there is no silver bullet for loging in to sites (sometimes the site itself is changing it as well - when it is revamped).

Answer (score 0):

Capture actual browser traffic with a tool like WireShark, look what it sends, and get back. Then copy behavior in you code. The base of your code is correct, you just have to tweak it.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer, if you downvote, please comment.